# Are there any open-source / free site analytics solutions that are intranet deployable?

Tags: open-source, analytics, intranet, web-analytics, web-statistics

There are plenty of statistics/analytics providers for Internet deployed software (e.g. Google Analytics), but I'm looking for an analytics tool to integrate into a LAN/intranet based web application.

I'm aware of [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), but I'd prefer something with a design similar to Google Analytics, where a Javascript callback can be embedded into the app and call back to an analytics server. This doesn't require any sort of extra application server configuration and access to run.

I'm thinking there's nothing available that isn't proprietary / pay-for, but I'd love to be told I'm wrong!

Comment: Here's a review of on premises web analytics software - it includes open source and commercial options:

http://analyticsmarket.com/blog/website-analytics-software-review

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org) should be able to meet your needs.  It's not as advanced as Google Analytics, but it uses a Javascript callback and can therefore give you more info than AWStats and Webalizer.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Webalizer, but its pretty ugly.

You can look at [Mint](http://haveamint.com/), it isn't free, but it costs $30 for the site, forever, so it is really a bargain for any large site.

Comment: Looks interesting but this might invalidate it http://haveamint.com/forum/pepper_development/2230/mint_for_an_internal_corporate_intranet

Comment: Ah bummer, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Piwik works great and I use it on some Intranet sites without a fully qualified domain name. But note that Piwik needs PHP to run. I've used it on Lunix and IIS servers though.

Answer (score 0):

If your intranet has a fully qualified domain name (ours is intranet.example.com, for instance) Google Analytics will work just fine. The admin interface will never tell you you've installed the tracking code properly, but it **will** collect data just fine.

I haven't tried it on a domain-less URL like http://intranet/. Worth a try, though.